# SQL Server 2008 Managment Studio Express instalation failure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've tried to install SQL Server 2008 Managment Studio Express using the Web platform installer. Installation. The installation have failed.

This was in the log

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Resuming previous install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading Install Plan from: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installplan.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing products to install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE install for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express'. Commandline is: 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\SQLManagementStudio\ec615068239a72bde129326745b6922681ec2374\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /q /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install /hideconsole /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 3092 - C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\SQLManagementStudio\ec615068239a72bde129326745b6922681ec2374\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express' is -2068578304
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Clearing cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193533'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product manager downloading: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193533
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-231145492.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/WebApplicationList.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product manager downloading: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/2.0/WebApplicationList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1221301405.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 5, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 2, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 5, minorOS: 2, majorSP: 2, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'SQLManagementStudio' was already in cart.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\SQLManagementStudio\ec615068239a72bde129326745b6922681ec2374\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe instead of downloading from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=186789&clcid=0x0409
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE install for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express'. Commandline is: 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\SQLManagementStudio\ec615068239a72bde129326745b6922681ec2374\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /q /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install /hideconsole /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 3384 - C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\SQLManagementStudio\ec615068239a72bde129326745b6922681ec2374\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express' is -2068578304
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express done              install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
```

**EDIT**

[detail.txt](http://paste-it.net/public/za25c8d/vim/)

Comment: Please post your detail.txt from %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\<latest session>

Comment: OK I've posted the detail.txt from the latest session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your detailed log shows you don't have enough space on C:. Make some room and retry, if it still fails please post the new detailed log.

Comment: Who could know that it will need over 2 GB of disk space :-)